# Constructing generalized Laplacian matrix?

Tags: numerics, computational-geometry, differential-equations, geometry, laplacian

I am staring intently at this paper by [Botsch and Kobbelt](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ejacobson/seminar/botsch-and-kobbelt-2004.pdf).

In particular, I want to make the matrix specified in equation 5. I am trying to understand the specific computations I must instruct a computer to produce the matrix.

The firs thing I tried is to check both wikipedia and [this book](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Elgliu/Courses/DGP_2014_autumn-winter/References/Book_Polygon%20Mesh%20Processing.pdf) (Appendix A.1) in both cases the description yields  a matrix that only works to get the laplacian of a scalar function, rather than a vector valued function.

Of course, a vector valued function is a vector of scalar functions, So I guess it's fine to create the Laplacian operator for the mesh $L \in \mathbb{R}^{|V|\times|V|}$ and then treat each coordinate function as its own scalar function?

So the full laplacian ends up being a stacked matrix:

$$ \boldsymbol{L} = \begin{bmatrix}
L \\
L \\
L
\end{bmatrix} $$

Such that given a vector of the vertex positions $X \in \mathbb{R}^{|V| \times 3}$ $\boldsymbol{L} X$ yields a $3|V| \times 1$ vector corresponding to the right laplacian?

But then $L$ is not a square matrix and as such it cannot be applied in a row $L L L$ the way the paper and the book talk about. since the dimensions don't match?

And then I am not entirely certain how do deal with the boundary conditions and the rings as specified in the paper.

I was hoping someone could lend me a hand.

Comment: You want a 3x3 block matrix where $L$ is on the diagonals.